# Python Error: "global name server_loop() is not defined"

Tags: python

I have been following along the "black hat python" book and when I typed in this particular code I got the error "global name server_loop() is not defined". Here is the statement BEFORE the main() function having the error:

```
if listen:
    server_loop()
```

and here is the server_loop() function IN the main() function:

```
def server_loop():
global target

# if no target is defined, we listen on all interfaces
if (not len(target)):
    target = "0.0.0.0"

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((target, port))
server.listen(5)

while True:
    client_socket, addr = server.accept()

    # spin off a thread to handle our new client
    client_thread = threading.Thread(target=client_handler, args=(client_socket,))
    client_thread.start()
```

Thanks

Comment: Your indentation is wrong for server_loop.  Everything below the def should be indented.  Also, nowhere do you define target.  Your `global target` statement just says to use the global, but in the code you show there isn't one

Comment: You're right, but I think indentation is not the issue here, just a post problem.

Comment: with the answer @Jean-FrançoisFabre provided, It would mean that the code from the book didn't work the way it was supposed to. Maybe the book had an error?

Comment: Or you misinterpreted what the book said. Does my answer solves your problem BTW?

Comment: would it be easier if I provided the full code?

Comment: I'll check if it solves....

Comment: *ticks answer* correct

Comment: Thanks! see my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understand the question correctly.

I can reproduce your case easily:

```
something()

def something():
    pass
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 420, in run_nodebug
  File "<module1>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'something' is not defined
```

If I call `something` after having defined it it works.

You *have* to define functions before using them.

I suppose that your book just gave the information in the inverted order (top => down, from global/main to implementation/function) expecting that you knew that as a lot of languages, python requires function definition before function call.
Personally I prefer single-block examples that you can type (or copy/paste) without thinking and it works right away.

Answer (score 1):

I also read this book, please arrange the function `server_loop` before the call of `main()` function.